# Linux doesn't detect Fn + F6 (toggle touchpad) combination on Lenovo V580 laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, touchpad, hotkeys

Though there is "toggle touchpad" secondary function on F6 button of my laptop currently this shortcut doesn't work.

`xbindkeys -mk` command doesn't show any info when I press Fn + F6.

I couldn't find related option in BIOS (to disable/enable the function).

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
...
```

Linux Mint 17.3 x86_64 Cinnamon